# Event receiver class

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

I have this class in my project:

```
class InputReactor
{
public:
    //Input reactor needs pointer to  Input
    InputReactor(Input* input_) :
        m_input(input_)
    {
    }

    virtual void input_quit(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_left(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_right(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_up(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_down(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_axisupd(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_ok(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_cancel(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_shift(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_ctrl(const float scale_);

    //All events reactor is subscribed at
    std::vector<EVENTS> subscribed_at;

    void setInputEnabled(bool inputEnabled_);
    bool isInputEnabled();

    //InputReactor automatically removes itself from subscribers
    virtual ~InputReactor()
    {
        for (EVENTS ev : subscribed_at)
        {
            m_input->unsubscribe(ev, this);
        }
    }

private:
    Input* m_input = nullptr;
    bool m_inputEnabled = false;

};
```

Any object that is derived from InputReactor can subscribe to different types of events (`enum class EVENTS`) in Input class and override required input_event function. Input class keeps `InputReactor*`. The problem is this part:

```
    //That could be a meme
    virtual void input_quit(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_left(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_right(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_up(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_down(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_axisupd(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_ok(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_cancel(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_shift(const float scale_);
    virtual void input_ctrl(const float scale_);
```

Making just a single regular method with `switch` inside would ruin the whole point, and it's impossible to override template method so i cannot simply make a single method like this:

```
template<EVENTS ev>
void input(const float scale_);
```

Probably I also could make a single template class for each EVENT and simply inherit all required, but that would make class definitions have tons of parents, and i wouldn't be able to enable / disable input with a single bool variable, so it's not better at all. Is there any way I can at least make it less ugly?

Comment: Inherit type list won't be too ugly with c++11, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7352569/1292791

Comment: In my opinion this is not really the correct usage of a reactor. The reactor class should not know about specific events. That should be handled in the event class. You may look a the following link, so see a reactor implementation according to the original definition. https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser  Please look in the reactor source files

Comment: @ArminMontigny , I didn't even knew about reactor pattern, but, if i got it's point correctly, I actually do the same. InputReactor class here is an EventHandler, and it is concreted in derived classes

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin , thanks, that looks like a good solution. One more question: how can I override pure virtual functions with same names from different classes if these classes are defined with a list? Solution like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150310/c-virtual-override-functions-with-same-name - does not work, compiler does not know about specific base classes

Comment: If you want to switch to the same function name, then we can't use inheritance and virtual function. We can consider somewhat like std::variant and type erasure. Actually, this kind of design will be faster than virtual functions.